# Как происходит запись в середину файла?

Tags: javascript, java, c++, python, xml

Верно ли, что нельзя дописать что-то не в конец файла, не перезаписав файл?
Как поступают, например, стандартные парсилки/редакторы XML (в любом языке программирования) если я вставляю значение поля в середине файла? Перезаписывают весь файл или только то, что после редактируемого места?

Answer (score 9):

И верно и неверно. В общем случае верно. Файл с точки зрения приложения представляет собой непрерывный кусок дисковой памяти. Запись в середину неминуемо приводит к затиранию существующих данных. Обычно программы либо перезаписывают файл целиком, либо начиная с точки изменения и до конца.

Однако, существует путь вставки данных в середину файла без перезаписи. Как известно, данные на диске хранятся в виде блоков и файл представляет собой совокупность блоков, причём где-то может храниться карта блоков для файла, либо же каждый блок содержит ссылку на последующий. Можно создать новый блок, записать в него данные и поменять карту, вставив ссылку на блок. Но у такого подхода есть и недостаток. Либо мы должны вставлять данные блоками определённого размера, либо использовать только часть блока и мириться с потерей части дисковой ёмкости.

Comment: "Блочный" (кластерный) метод используется во многих СУБД(не вовсех). XML не поддерживает блочность. Ещё блочность поддерживает biff обвёртка (doc, xls и некоторые другие офиса), в новом офисе от блочности отказались. Спецификация файла либо предусмативает разбивку на адресуемые блоки (в mp3 они не адресуемые) либо нет.

Comment: [fallocate(2) на Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) поддерживает вставку/удаление без перезаписи (с ограничениями). Хотя, при работе с xml крайне вероятно, что всё после редактируемого места просто переписывается. Чтобы в случае ошибки сохранить оригинал или для больших файлов, может использоваться временный файл куда новое содержимое пишется и в конце в случае успеха он переименовывается: [edit text file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1582750/4279)

Comment: С тем же успехом можно перезаписывать и отдельными символами - лишь бы их было ровно столько же, сколько затирается.

Comment: @Harry для ясности: методы типа `fallocate()` не просто отдельные байты позволяют переписывать, по месту не копируя—эта функция позволяет менять длину файла (с ограничениями вставлять/удалять, в том числе и в середине).

Answer (score 9):

Почти любые стандартные и нестандартные средства работают не напрямую с диском или файловой системой тома, а обращаются с запросами на действие к файловому реквестору. Тот соответственно транслирует файловые операции в дисковые (и обратно), инициируя чтение или запись физических секторов.

Если файл полностью считывается в память процесса и потом полностью записывается обратно, то дисковая подсистема тупо выполнит всё запрошенное, и запишет старую информацию поверх новой, несмотря на то, что в ней ни бита не поменялось (это я про "голову файла" до точки внесения изменений) - так дешевле, чем сравнивать то, что было, с тем, что стало.

Но если процесс считывает некоторое "окно", в которое вносятся изменения, и затем это новое состояние сбрасывается на диск, то перезаписыванию подвергнутся только секторы, которые относятся в этому окну. И именно приложение, чтобы не поломать файл, вынуждено будет организовывать чтение следующих "окон", смещение в них информации и запись их нового состояния - и так до конца файла. Процесс, как понимаете, дорогой, а память нынче дёшева - потому подавляющее большинство приложений не занимаются подобным "крохоборством" и для изменения читают, а после изменения пишут, весь файл целиком.

А чтобы при этом не нарваться на проблемы, предпочтительным является не перезапись поверх, а запись нового файла с переименованием и/или удалением старого. Поиск свободного пространства под файл, по возможности непрерывного - тоже недорогая операция, так что новый файл скорее всего окажется физически совсем не в том месте, где лежал файл до корректировки. А заодно такая методика является и пассивным методом борьбы с фрагментацией.

Answer (score 5):

Стандартные парсилки/редакторы XML считывают файл полностью в оперативную память, а потом также полностью записывают его на диск. Для компьютера это гораздо проще и быстрее. Если работать напрямую с жестким диском, то это будет ОЧЕНЬ медленно.

Comment: А если файл размером в несколько гигабайт?

Comment: @Harry - тогда xml- неудачный формат хранения

Comment: @Harry Если файл несколько гигабайт, что лучше поискать другой формат для хранения. Как вариант можно попробовать разбить xml на несколько частей, потом загружать в память какие-нибудь заголовки или вводные слова для каждой части. По этим словам находить нужную тебе часть и загружать её в оперативку, чтобы с ней работать. В самом конце склеивать файлы в один большой XML. Хотя это тоже не очень хороший вариант в плане скорости, но хоть какое-то решение.

Comment: @evilnw, а можно ссылку на доку какой-нибудь стандартной, где об этом сказано?

Comment: @G0ohan, к сожалению, я даже не смогу найти. Когда-то давно читал статью, где похожим способом пытались обойти ограничение на количество оперативной памяти, но там всё гораздо хуже. Было устройство, у которого всего 5 мб оперативной памяти и требовалось парсить разные таблицы и тексты, которые могли занимать по 10-20 мб. Основной файл разбивался на кучу маленьких и на каждый такой файл вешались вводные слова, по которым можно быстро найти нужную часть. Далее программа открывала этот небольшой файл и доставала\записывала нужные значение. В конце все файлы собирались в один.

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно.

Зависит от реализации. Вполне допускаю, что файл полностью считывается в память, обрабатывается и полностью сбрасывается на диск.